# Is it bad to throw custom exceptions inside custom filter and then handle them in ErrorController?

Tags: java, spring, exception, filter, controller

There are many tutorials out there that show how to implement your own custom error response in case you don't like the verbose default that spring uses.
I managed to overcome any problem until now that i decided to use jwt filter to authenticate users.

In general, i use a RestControllerAdvice - global handler

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {...}
```

to catch all the exceptions thrown from controllers or services.

Now i find out that this handler won't work for exception thrown inside filters. Here is my jwt filter.

```
public class JwtTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    public JwtTokenFilter(JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider) {
        this.jwtTokenProvider = jwtTokenProvider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
            FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        
        httpServletRequest.setAttribute("initialPath", httpServletRequest.getRequestURI());

        if (httpServletRequest.getHeader("Authorization") == null) {
            throw new TokenException("Authorization field is empty.");
        }
        String token = jwtTokenProvider.resolveToken(httpServletRequest);
        if (token == null) {
            throw new TokenException("Non Bearer Token");
        }

        // throws TokenException
        jwtTokenProvider.validateToken(token);
        // throws NoUserFoundException
        Authentication auth = jwtTokenProvider.getAuthentication(token);

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
            
        filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
    }
}
```

I also found out that you can have a custom error controller that you can handle these errors like this

```
@RestController
public class CustomErrorController implements ErrorController {
    
    private static final String PATH = "/error";
    
    @RequestMapping(PATH)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleError(final HttpServletRequest request,
            final HttpServletResponse response) throws Throwable {
        
        Throwable ex = (Throwable) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception");
        String initialPath = (String)request.getAttribute("initialPath");
        
        // User requested at /error endpoint. Let GlobalExceptionHandler handle it.
        // Any other case in which ex can be null?
        if (ex == null) {
            throw new NoHandlerFoundException("", "/error" ,null);
        }

        ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, ex.getMessage());  
        errorResponse.setPath(initialPath);

        return ResponseEntity.status(errorResponse.getStatus()).body(errorResponse);
    }
    
    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return PATH;
    }
}
```

I need to work more on my backend to see that everything could work out this way. However i wanted to ask: is this a good approach?
A exception thrown inside filter will give this output on my terminal

```
2021-07-18 22:04:24.188 ERROR 21729 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception

com.example.demo.exception.TokenException: Authorization field is empty.
        at com.example.demo.security.JwtTokenFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtTokenFilter.java:27) ~[main/:na]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
```

I suppose i get this because since a filter calls another filter (like a chain), no one will finish its' execution because of the exception. So, it is a bad thing that all these filters don't finish the job?

Note that for exception handled by my global handler i get `WARN` messages but for exceptions handled by `CustomErrorController` i get `ERROR` messages.

Answer (score -1):

I hope this answers you question.

Well, I have been using a similar approach to yours for a while (Controller advice and general exception handler), now for the filter exception, I use a `@Component` and `AuthenticationEntryPoint` and let spring boot handle it rather than checking for it. So, you just catch the exceptions in the filter and log them there, and spring handles the response to your api client.

```java
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7858869558953243875L;

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                         AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        response.getWriter().append(gson.toJson(new ErrorResponse(ErrorBody.UNAUTHORIZED)));
        response.setStatus(401);
    }
}
```

I hope I've helped you with this, it might not fit your use case tho, if does not, please comment and we will modify.

Cheers!